# web.py on Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, web.py

I'm trying to get a `web.py` application running on GAE. I hoped that sth like the following might work

```
import web
from google.appengine.ext.webapp.util import run_wsgi_app

[...]

def main():
    app = web.application(urls, globals())
    run_wsgi_app(app)
```

But obviously the `app` object doesn't conform with the `run_wsgi_app` function's expectations. The error msg says sth like `app has no __call__ function`, so I tried passing `app.run` instead, but that didn't work either.

How can I make the call to `run_wsgi_app` work?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is a snippet of [StackPrinter](http://stackprinter.appspot.com/), a [webpy](http://webpy.org/) application that runs on top of Google App Engine.

```
from google.appengine.ext.webapp.util import run_wsgi_app
import web
...
app = web.application(urls, globals())

def main():

    application = app.wsgifunc()
    run_wsgi_app(application)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to import or use run_wsgi_app, web.py has a runcgi method that works perfectly!

```
if __name__  == '__main__':
    app.cgirun()
```

Comment: Why not just use `app.run()`? web.py should be able to figure out that it need to run the app as cgi.